# Trying to save the picture onto another folder by adding random number In front of the picture

Tags: php, html

In my website there is, 6 digit random numbers known as `refno` Example `20221234`and there is fileupload. Right now, it saves the photos with its own name on to the another filepath example`cat.png`. Currently, I tried to add that `refno`in front of the picture while saving like`20221234cat.png`. Is that possible to do?

```
<?php    
$refno = isset ($_GET['refno'])? $_GET['refno']:'';
    $file = isset($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])? $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] : "";
    $file_size = isset($_FILES["file"]["size"])? $_FILES["file"]["size"] : "";
    $file_name = isset($_FILES["file"]["name"])? $_FILES["file"]["name"] : "";
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $dataDir = "//sgewsnant21.amk.st.com/ews/web/webspool/temp/visualdefectreport/";


             
    if ($file_size <= 0)
        
    {
        echo "<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">";
        echo "  alert('No picture attached!')";
        //echo $refno;
        echo "</script>";
        
    }
    else
    {
           
        if(stristr($file_name, ".png")){
            $connection = mysqli_connect($apews_db_apews2, $apews_db_usr, $apews_db_pwd) or die ("Unableeeee to connect!");
            $dest = $dataDir.$file_name;

            if(move_uploaded_file($file,$dest))
            {
                echo "<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">";
            echo "  alert('Visual Defect Report and pictures are successfully submitted!')";
            //echo $refno;
          echo "</script>";
          
            }
        }
        else if(stristr($file_name, ".jpg")){
            $connection = mysqli_connect($apews_db_apews2, $apews_db_usr, $apews_db_pwd) or die ("Unableeeee to connect!");
            $dest = $dataDir.$file_name;

            if(move_uploaded_file($file,$dest))
            {
                echo "<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">";
            echo "  alert('Visual Defect Report and pictures are successfully submitted!')";
            //echo $refno;
          echo "</script>";
          
            }
        }
        else if(stristr($file_name, ".jpeg")){
            $connection = mysqli_connect($apews_db_apews2, $apews_db_usr, $apews_db_pwd) or die ("Unableeeee to connect!");
            $dest = $dataDir.$file_name;

            if(move_uploaded_file($file,$dest))
            {
                echo "<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">";
            echo "  alert('Visual Defect Report and pictures are successfully submitted!')";
            //echo $refno;
          echo "</script>";
            }
    

        }
        }
    }
        
    
      $file_name= "//sgewsnant21.amk.st.com/ews/web/webspool/temp/visualdefectreport/" . $refno.$file_name;

        flush();
    mysqli_close($conn);

    ?>
```

Below is how I get the `refno`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    const now = new Date();
    let randomNum = '';
    randomNum += Math.round(Math.random() * 9);
    randomNum += Math.round(Math.random() * 9);
    randomNum += now.getTime().toString().slice(-2);
    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById("refno").value = `${new Date().getFullYear()}${randomNum}`;
    }
    
    </script>

  <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="refno">REF nos :</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <p class="form-control-static" style="margin-top: -6px;">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="refno" name="refno" value="<?php echo $refno;?>" disabled>
        
    </p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php    
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    
        $refno = isset ($_GET['refno'])? $_GET['refno']:'';
        $file_tmp = isset($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])? $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] : "";
        $file_size = isset($_FILES["file"]["size"])? $_FILES["file"]["size"] : "";
        $file_name = isset($_FILES["file"]["name"])? $_FILES["file"]["name"] : "";
        
        //Images Directory
        $dataDir = "//sgewsnant21.amk.st.com/ews/web/webspool/temp/visualdefectreport/";
        
        //New Filename
        $new_filename = $dataDir.$refno.$file_name;
        
        //File formats
        $file_formats=array("jpeg","jpg","png");
        
        //echo $file_size;
        if($file_size>0){
            //echo "Good";
            $file_info = pathinfo($file_name);
            $file_ext= $file_info['extension'];
            
            //check the extension
            if(in_array($file_ext,$file_formats))
                {
                    //Database Connection 
                    //$connection = mysqli_connect($apews_db_apews2, $apews_db_usr, $apews_db_pwd, $database) or die ("Unableeeee to connect!");
                    if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $new_filename))
                    {
                        $message="alert('Visual Defect Report and pictures are successfully submitted!')";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $message= "  alert('Error Uploading File!')";
                    }                   
                    
                }
            else
                {
                    $message= "  alert('Invalid Picture Format!')";
                }
        }
        else
        {
            $message= "  alert('No picture attached!')";
        }
                 
        echo "<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">";
        echo $message;
        //echo $refno;
        echo "</script>";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['saveimage']))
{
    $directory="images/";
    $filename =$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $filename_temp =$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $new_filename = $directory.date("YmdHis")."_".$filename;
    
    if(move_uploaded_file($filename_temp,$new_filename))
        {
            echo "File Uploaded ";
        }
    else
        {
            echo "File Upload Error.";
        }
}
echo "<hr/>";
?>
 <form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="file" />
 <input type="submit" name="saveimage" value="save" />
 </form>
```

Comment: Can you please do the edit based on my codes?

Comment: i Updated your code, check with local folder and try